# Flask crashes with ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi, werkzeug

I have a flask app which communicates with another web service. I have this error which only seems to occur when both applications are running on the same server, but I don't know what the source is. The Flask application is hosted at `/tools` via a `WSGIScriptAlias` in Apache.

```
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114] mod_wsgi (pid=25705): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/tools-frontend/wsgi.py'.
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1361, in full_dispatch_request
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     response = self.make_response(rv)
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1447, in make_response
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     rv = self.response_class(rv, headers=headers, status=status)
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 627, in __init__
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     self.headers = Headers(headers)
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 836, in __init__
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     self.extend(defaults)
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]   File "/opt/tools-frontend/ENV_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 978, in extend
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114]     for key, value in iterable:
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [error] [client 41.164.8.114] ValueError: too many values to unpack
[Thu May 23 13:11:44 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 41.164.8.114] Zlib: Compressed 590 to 372 : URL /tools/api/login/, referer: http://www.website.com/tools
```

The API is hosted at a different domain on the same machine, looking at the log file for that, it is working correctly.

The API call is made in the following functions:

```
@app.route('/api/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@app.route('/api/<path:endpoint>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def api(endpoint=None):
    # extract POST/PUT variables
    dat = request.form
    if len(dat) == 0:
        # extract GET variables
        dat = request.args
    # submit request to API
    out = call_api(request.method, endpoint, dat, request.files)
    return out
```

which calls:

```
def call_api(method, endpoint, data=None, files=None):
    url = 'https://api.example.com' + endpoint
    if method.upper() == "GET":
        r = requests.get(url, data=data, verify=False)
    # ... similarly for other verbs  
    return r.text, r.status_code, r.headers
```

Comment: Are you trying to set headers in your view? Could you share the code? The value of `headers` isnt `None`, and isnt a dict, but is iterable. Iterable's should yield `(key, value)` pairs, but thats not what its getting.

Comment: It seems to me that the crash is occurring when flask/werkzeug is attempting to process the response. You can see in the stack trace that my code is not involved at all, the top file is `flask/app/py`.

The line the triggers the API call is `r = requests.get(url, data=data, verify=False)`

Comment: Can you share your view code? Its choking  parsing the headers of the response, your code isnt in the stack trace because the error isnt in your view yes, but it doesnt mean it isnt the cause - it generates the response after all.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My best guess is that you return a special headers dictionary (from python-requests) instead of a normal one. Flask takes the headers in two forms:

```
{'key': 'value'}
# and
[('key', 'value')]
```

Since your special dict is not recognized as a real dict, it will be treated like a list of tuples, which fails.

Change

```
return r.text, r.status_code, r.headers
```

to

```
return r.text, r.status_code, r.headers.items()
```

Comment: I cannot possibly up-vote this enough! You solved a week of pain and frustration.